# Oracle to SQL Server migration

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am working on server migration from Oracle to SQL Server 2012.

In a stored procedure I have

```
select 
    @Months = datediff(m, getdate(), cast('12/01/' + CAST(year(getdate()) + 1 as varchar(4)) as datetime))
```

Do I need to make any changes to this query to run it successfully in SQL Server? Or it will work fine as it is ? The functions used here (in Oracle) are almost works same in SQL Server (right now I don't have link server to test).

Comment: Best thing you can do is to test it yourself in SQL Server.  If you are doing a migration, you absolutely need to get access to SQL Server as part of your project.  SQL Server Express is free, so cost shouldn't be a barrier. In the meantime you might be able to test things out on http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: I've ran it on sql fiddle and got back 20. [see for yourself.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74f6d/1)
However, when dealing with dates and not specifing formats it's best to use standard ANSI format (yyyy-MM-dd)

Comment: I am waiting to get access to SQL server. sqlfiddle.com.  is very useful thank you DWright for your help..

Comment: your should check [sqldeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index-097090.html), it has migration tools that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

getdate(), datediff(), and Cast() are all valid in SQL Server

Comment: I would not think so, with that query.  However, if you're migrating a whole system, you should test everything.

Comment: you are right I am testing all query and all configuration things .